# Build UI programmatically for OS X in Swift (without Interface Builder)

Tags: macos, swift, appcode

I am new to Swift and I want to develop an OS X app using AppCode (I do not want to use XCode), and without storyboards. So I need to build the UI and manage outlets and actions programmatically.
I am looking for a link to a sample code / tutorial video for a "Hello World" or sample app in which the UI is created programmatically. Appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: What's your rationale for this?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : rationale for what ? using AppCode or not using UIStuff?

Comment: Not using storyboards and the like. Isn't that how apple wants you to do it?

Comment: I am using AppCode instead of XCode. AppCode does not support storyboards or nibs on OS X apps (only on iOS apps). So I need to do UI programmatically. Also, code gives more flexibility. An article for comparison: http://www.toptal.com/ios/ios-user-interfaces-storyboards-vs-nibs-vs-custom-code

Comment: @coconutwater Element is a programmatic UI framework for macOS soon iOS: https://github.com/eonist/Element  (I'm the main contributor to Element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let newWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.width/2, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.height/2), styleMask: NSTitledWindowMask|NSResizableWindowMask|NSMiniaturizableWindowMask|NSClosableWindowMask, backing: NSBackingStoreType.Buffered, defer: false)
    let newText = NSTextField(frame: NSMakeRect(0, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.height/4, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.width/2, 40))
    let myView = NSView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.width/2, NSScreen.mainScreen()!.frame.height/2))

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        newText.font = NSFont(name: "Arial Black", size: 24)
        newText.backgroundColor = NSColor.clearColor()
        newText.bordered = false
        newText.textColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
        newText.alignment = .CenterTextAlignment
        newText.stringValue = "Hello World"
        newText.selectable = false
        newWindow.opaque = false
        newWindow.movableByWindowBackground = true
        newWindow.backgroundColor = NSColor(calibratedHue: 0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 0, alpha: 0.7)
        newWindow.title = "Hello World"
        newWindow.center()
        newWindow.contentView.addSubview(myView)
        myView.addSubview(newText)
        newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! It looks the the snippet doesn't work in Xcode, right? How do I need to configure it so that I can use it there?

I already tried moving the 'MainMenu.xib' file into trash and removing the reference from the project info. After that, I tried your snippet within my 'AppDelegate.swift' but as soon as I let Xcode build my app, there's no window popping up and I get two errors instead:

_Failed to connect (view and colorGridView) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSColorPickerGridView): missing setter or instance variable_ -

What do I need to do to get my app running? Thanks! =)